# Deleted glyph from SVG and the icon is still appearing on the website

Tags: web-development, fonts

I am trying to delete an unwanted glyph from a website by opening the SVG file in BirdFont and just deleting the font from the board. I had deleted the graphic and it's still appearing on the website. How do I go about removing this unwanted glyph?

Answer (score 1):

The font might be cached in your web browser. Press Ctrl and click on reload to refresh the font in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Most of these sound too simple to forget, and that's why you forget to check:

- Make sure you've uploaded the file. Do it again to be sure
- Check the source of the image to make sure it's gone
- Press CTRL+F5 to do a hard reload (means 'also clear cache').